# Close materialize modal from center to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I'm working on an application with Materialize. I'm trying to open and close a modal with a "linear transition". 
I mean, I would like open it from top to center and, close it from center to bottom.

At the moment i succeed in the first case (open it from top to center) but i didn't find a way to close it as I want.

I tried to reach my goal through css, so I used this class:

```
.modal-slide-show {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

I have searched a lot, but I didn't find a way for a custom close of modal. 
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nb5sv2x5/2/), you can find a fiddle in order to check a simple example

**Edit**
I'm using materialize 0.97.7

Comment: Do you have a problem with editing materialize plugin script file ?

Comment: @DanPhilip, it should be better to not modify it, but also this solution is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you could edit the plugin file just find this code and change the `endingTop` to 14%.

```
var methods = {
    init : function(options) {
      var defaults = {
        opacity: 0.5,
        inDuration: 350,
        outDuration: 250,
        ready: undefined,
        complete: undefined,
        dismissible: true,
        startingTop: '4%',
        endingTop: '14%'
      };
```

This should apply the change throughout the website and all the modals should close to bottom and open from top and no worries about the method by which it is closed.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I didn't find this piece of code in materialize.js. I'm working with 0.97.7 version. Is it possible use it?

Comment: I took the code from the external resource you mentioned in your fiddle. It should be there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a class `.bye` which moves the position of your modal to `top: 100%` so that the modal vanishes from the center to the bottom.

The `setTimeout` is to remove the same class from your modal once the modal is gone so that when you click it the next time it appears from top to center.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal1').modal();
  $(".modal-close").click(function() {
    $(".modal").addClass("bye");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".modal").removeClass("bye");
    }, 700);
  });
});

.bye {
  top: 100% !important;
}

.modal-slide-show {
  transform: none !important;
  transition: all .5s !important;
}
```

Check updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/nb5sv2x5/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/darshan1/nb5sv2x5/4/):

```
 $('.modal').modal({
      dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
      opacity: .5, // Opacity of modal background
      inDuration: 300, // Transition in duration
      outDuration: 200, // Transition out duration
      startingTop: '70%', // Starting top style attribute
      endingTop: '60%', // Ending top style attribute
      ready: function(modal, trigger) { // Callback for Modal open. Modal and trigger parameters available.

      }
    }
  );
```